# Convert SQL Sub Query to In to Linq Lambda

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How do I convert the following SQL statement into Lambda Expression or Linq Query?

The following query get the single most recent Answer for each Question. Or to phrase it another way, get each Question with the newest Answer.

Also this will be execute by Entity Framework.

```
SELECT Answers.*
FROM Answers
Where AnswerID IN
(
    SELECT Max(AnswerID) AnswerID
    FROM Answers
    GROUP BY QuestionID
)
```

Here another way to look at the previous query using an Inner Join

```
SELECT answers.* 
FROM answers 
INNER JOIN  
(
     SELECT Max(answerID) answerID --,  QuestionSiteID
     FROM answers
     GROUP BY QuestionID 
) t ON
     answers.answerID = t.answerID
```

I have read that the LINQ Contains method is sub optimal for queries that access SQL.
[LINQ to Sql and .Contains() trap.](http://www.aristo-samar.com/blognet/post/2009/07/06/LINQ-to-Sql-and-Contain%28%29-clausule-trap.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could do this using something like:

```
 var subQuery = from a in answers
                group a by a.QuestionID into grouping
                select new
                {
                    QuestionID = grouping.Key,
                    MaxAnswerID = grouping.Max(x => x.AnswerID)
                };

 var query = from a in answers
             from s in subQuery
             where a.AnswerID == s.MaxAnswerID
             select a;
```

This results in a CROSS JOIN in the generated SQL

---

Also, you could use `join` in the second part of the query:

```
 var query = from a in answers
             join s in subQuery on a.AnswerID equals s.MaxAnswerID
             select a;
```

This results in a INNER JOIN in the SQL

---

Note for side cases - the above answers make the reasonable assumption that `AnswerID` is the primary key of `Answers` - if you happen to have instead a table design which is keyed on (AnswerID, QuestionID) then you will need to join by both AnswerID and QuestionID like:

```
 var subQuery = from a in answers
                group a by a.QuestionID into grouping
                select new
                {
                    QuestionID = grouping.Key,
                    MaxAnswerID = grouping.Max(x => x.AnswerID)
                };

 var query = from a in answers
             from s in subQuery
             where a.AnswerID == s.MaxAnswerID
             && a.QuestionID == s.QuestionID
             select a;
```

See the comment trail for more discussion on this alternate table design...

Comment: Stuart thank for the answer.  When I ran you LINQ Query in LinqPad it returned the results I expected.  I also noticed that only one query is executed.  This looks great.  I provided a answer also and both of ours created the same query execution plan. The sql that was created for you included a cross join and my sql was an inner join, but as I said the SQL query execution plan was the same.  Good job

Comment: Yeah - I love the way that you can chain Linq queries together and it generates just a single SQL query at the end (you can also return the subqueries from C# functions). Feel free to mark answers as accepted instead of supplying your own ;)

Comment: Also, while you've got the query execution plans to hand - what's the impact of using/not using `join`?

Comment: Just ran your 2nd query in LinqPad and it work.  For those who may be wondering, it create an Inner Join SQL query.  I havn't tested these in EF yet, but I'm pretty confident they will work.

Comment: @Stuart: Per your comment "using/not using join", I noticed that your 1st linq query created a SQL Cross Join and your 2nd linq query created a SQL Inner Join.  Both queries created same SQL Execution Plan

Comment: Just tested this and it returns 7 rows for my 4 row test table.  Looks like you'd have to add `where a.QuestionID == s.QuestionID` to the bottom query

Comment: @Andomar - isn't that already covered by the grouping in the subQuery? (assuming that AnswerID has a Unique constraint)

Comment: @BarDeb - interesting on the cross join vs inner join observation - and that for your table structure they have the same execution plan - thanks.

Comment: @Stuart: Test it on this table: `create table Answers(AnswerID int, QuestionID int) insert Answers values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1);`  I'll downvote your answer since it returns the wrong results.

Comment: @Andomar - your table has multiple Answers with the same AnswerID. You are obviously free to downvote all you like, but I think that in the OP "AnswerID" is a unique ID for the Answer table... so if your test data has multiple answers all with ID of 1, then I personally think it's your test data that is wrong.... I believe a valid set of test data might be (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,1). As I say, feel free to downvote - I know I can't please all of the people all of the time :)

Comment: @Andomar - to be clear on this, your complaint would seem to be valid in the case where the Answer table has a primary key like - (AnswerId, QuestionId) - but really I'm not sure that's a reasonable assumption to make here... I've changed my answer to reflect my assumption.

Comment: @Stuart: Seems like a reasonable assumption really, I'll remove the downvote.  It was just that with the first example I typed in the results were wrong.

Comment: Thanks - have added a comment in the answer - but I did hit a conflict on saving - hope I didn't lose/overwrite anything.

Comment: Weird - looks like removing a downvote is marked as a question edit in the SO database.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `let` statement to select the first answer per QuestionID group:

```
from answer in Answers
group answer by answer.QuestionID into question
let firstAnswer = question.OrderByDescending(q => q.AnswerID).First()
select firstAnswer
```

EDIT: Linq2Sql translates the above query into a N+1 database calls. This query gets translated to just one SQL query:

```
from a in Answers
group a by a.QuestionID into grouping
join a2 in Answers on 
    new {AnswerID = grouping.Max(x => x.AnswerID), QuestionID = grouping.Key} 
    equals new {a2.AnswerID, a2.QuestionID}
select a2
```

Makes me wonder in what way Linq2Sql is supposed to be simpler than SQL.

Comment: Should it be `OrderByDescending`?

Comment: +1 for this answer - I like the look of it! Would be interested to know - what is the SQL it gets translated into - is it a query with a subquery inside?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I ran the statement LinqPad and it retrieved the results I expected.  I also noticed that there is a sql statement created for each question in the system.  If I have 100 questions then 100 queries will be ran.

Comment: @Bar: Try to replace `First()` with `Take(1)`

Comment: @Bar, Lad: Or change `in Answers` to `in Answers.ToList()`

Comment: @Landislav: Take(1) create the same sql; a query for each question.  I'm not sure where you want me to put ToList(). Even if I added ToList(), I believe it would not be beneficial becuase it would force a database call.

Comment: @Bar: The `.ToList()` goes at the end of the first line.  It will change the rest of the query to Linq2Objects; the one and only database call will come from `ToList()`

Comment: Ouch - reading this I'd like to remove my +1... looks like it's very inefficient. You don't want to do N queries and you don't want to fetch all the answers into your app's RAM.

Comment: I agree with Stuat.  Currently there are only 200 records in the Answers table, but there could be 200,000 answers.  I don't want to pull all of those records back if I'm not going to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query:

```
var query = from c in context.Childs
            group c by c.ParentEntityId into pc
            select pc.OrderByDescending(pcc => pcc.Id).Take(1);
```

I just checked the query in profiler and it produces single SQL query (the ugly one):

```
SELECT 
[Project3].[ParentEntityId] AS [ParentEntityId], 
[Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project3].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project3].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project3].[ParentEntityId1] AS [ParentEntityId1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[ParentEntityId] AS [ParentEntityId], 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Limit1].[ParentEntityId] AS [ParentEntityId1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Limit1].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[ParentEntityId] AS [ParentEntityId]
        FROM [dbo].[ChildEntities] AS [Extent1] ) AS [Distinct1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], [Project2].[ParentEntityId] AS [ParentEntityId]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Extent2].[ParentEntityId] AS [ParentEntityId]
            FROM [dbo].[ChildEntities] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Distinct1].[ParentEntityId] = [Extent2].[ParentEntityId]) OR (([Distinct1].[ParentEntityId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[ParentEntityId] IS NULL))
        )  AS [Project2]
        ORDER BY [Project2].[Id] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
)  AS [Project3]
ORDER BY [Project3].[ParentEntityId] ASC, [Project3].[C1] ASC
```

Comment: Also results in N+1 queries... strange

Comment: For me this LINQ gives multiple queries like `SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[AnswerID], [t0].[QuestionID]
FROM [Answers] AS [t0]
WHERE ((@x1 IS NULL) AND ([t0].[QuestionID] IS NULL)) OR ((@x1 IS NOT NULL) AND ([t0].[QuestionID] IS NOT NULL) AND (@x1 = [t0].[QuestionID]))
ORDER BY [t0].[AnswerID] DESC`

Comment: Interesting. I'm using Entity framework against SQL Server 2008. What's your configuration? I can imagine that multiple queries will be run with Linq-to-Sql but I haven't seen this in Linq-to-entities.

Comment: Now I see you mentioned Linq-to-Sql in your answer. Those two are different beasts. Linq-to-sql somehow optimizes queries and makes it own decision when single or multiple queries should be run. Linq-to-entities with default SQL provider always creates single query.

Comment: I'm using LinqPad against SQL2008R2, so that could explain the difference.  An `outer apply` with `top 1` is pretty inefficient too, but it looks like EF is at least avoiding the round trip!

Comment: @Andomar: Yes this one is definitely inefficient. I thought about deleting my answer but I let it be just as another not very good approach.