# LINQ Where Exists GROUP BY

Tags: sql, linq, group-by, exists

How can i convert this in LINQ?

```
SELECT B.SENDER, B.SENDNUMBER, B.SMSTIME, B.SMSTEXT
FROM MESSAGES B
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT A.SENDER
        FROM MESSAGES A
    WHERE A.SENDER = B.SENDER
    GROUP BY A.SENDER
    HAVING B.SMSTIME = MAX( A.SMSTIME))
GROUP BY B.SENDER, B.SENDNUMBER, B.SMSTIME, B.SMSTEXT ;
```

Thanks a lot :)

EDIT!!

Resolved with:

```
  var Condition = "order by SMSTime desc";      

  IEnumerable<ClassMessaggio> messaggi = Database.Select<ClassMessaggio>(Condition);; // Load all but sorted

  ElencoConversazioni =  messaggi.GroupBy(m => new { m.Number })
                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.SMSTime).First()).ToObservableCollection();
```

Comment: What's the outer `GROUP BY` for? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i've a list of messsages from some contacts, i need to show a list of "conversations" with the last message of every contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
db.Messages.Where(b => b.SmsTime == Messages.Where(a => a.Sender == b.Sender)
                                            .Max(a => a.SmsTime))
```

Or

```
db.Messsages.GroupBy(m => new { m.Sender, m.SendNumber })
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.SmsTime).First())
```

Where `db` is your DataContext.

Comment: My table is "ClassMessaggio", so i substitute Messages with ClassMessaggio, but it give me: "No field or method 'ClassMessaggio' in class JackSMS.ClassMessaggio in position 15"

Comment: Huh? You need to run this on an instance (it's not a `static` method).  Use a DataContext.

Comment: i have this: var condition = "ClassMessaggio.GroupBy(m => new {m.Sender, m.SendNumber, m.OtherThings}).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.SmsTime).First())";
               ElencoConversazioni = Database.Select<ClassMessaggio>(condition).ToObservableCollection();    What do i wrong?

Comment: uhm.. but with simple condition it work: Conversazione = Database.Select<ClassMessaggio>("Number='" + Number + "' order by SMSTime asc").ToObservableCollection(); i'll give it a read, thanks..

Comment: Huh? What exactly are you using? That sounds like DLINQ.

Comment: I'm using Perst Database, and i read it use LINQ for condition.. ??

Comment: I don't know; I've never heard of it.  That's not LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your LINQ. I resolved as i wrote in first post!

Answer (score 0):

To show the list of conversations along with "the last message of every contact", you could try something like:

```
// a query to find the last Sms time per sender
var lastSmsQuery = from m in db.messages
                 group m by m.Sender into grouping
                 select new
                 {
                     Sender = grouping.Key,
                     LastSmsTime = grouping.Max(x => x.SmsTime)
                 };

// a query to find the messages linked to the last Sms per sender
var lastMessageQuery = from m in db.messages
                       join l in lastSmsQuery on new { m.Sender, m.SmsTime } equals new { l.Sender, l.LastSmsTime }
                       select m;
```

The 2-query method used is similar to that of this question from earlier today - [Convert SQL Sub Query to In to Linq Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528103/convert-sql-sub-query-to-in-to-linq-lambda/5528222#5528222)

Comment: As i understand with the other answer, I think the problem is i don't need to use exactly LINQ with Perst DB. i'll try to find what i have to use for query from DB and i'll question again. thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Never used Perst - but Bing tells me that it can support some Linq querying - good luck!