# Lambda expression query of MySQL query

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, lambda

I am trying to write lambda expression of MySQL query with respect of Parent Child relationship table but I didn't get a proper output in respect of data, so can any one tell me how we will write that.

```
Parent_Type(Parent Table) :-  
CREATE  TABLE `Parent_Type` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `NAME` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `FLAG` decimal(1,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );
```

Child_Type(Child Table) :-

```
CREATE  TABLE `Child_Type` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `NAME` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `Parent_TYPE_ID` INT NULL,
  `FLAG` decimal(1,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),INDEX `fk_Child_Type_1` (`PARENT_TYPE_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Child_Type_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PARENT_TYPE_ID` )
    REFERENCES `parent_type` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Dummy Data:-
ParentType-

```
ID         Name     FLag
```

```
 1          A         0
 2          B         0
 3          C         1
```

ChildType :-

```
Id---------Name-----------------Parent_Type_Id-------Flag
```

```
 1          GA                      1                   0
 2          GB                      1                   1
 3          GC                      2                   1
 4          GD                      2                   0
 5          GE                      3                   0
```

MySQL Query:-

```
SELECT * from parent_type p left outer join child_type c
on p.ID = c.PARENT_TYPE_ID where p.flag=0 AND c.flag=0;
```

So, I need that data which has flag=0 in both table.
OutputData :-

```
Id  Parent_Type_Id   Name    ChildName         Flag
```

```
1   1                 A         GA                0
4   2                 B         GD                0
```

Upper Query is running and the output is giving properly. Can anyone tell me how this query will be done in lambda expression.

Comment: Parent_Type_Id is the FK in Child_Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ....

var lambdaExpression = ParentType.Where(c => c.Flag == 0)
                          .Join(ChildType.Where(uc => uc.Flag == 0), c => new { c.Name, c.ID }, uc => new { uc.Name, uc.ID },
                          (c, uc) => c);

If still face some issue see this ...

[Convert SQL Sub Query to In to Linq Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528103/convert-sql-sub-query-to-in-to-linq-lambda)

[How to convert an expression tree to a partial SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731905/how-to-convert-an-expression-tree-to-a-partial-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Plz share ur lamda expression.... 
Try this, may be this c an help You.

IList parentList=parent_type.Where(x=>x.FLAG==0 && (x=>x.child_type.where(t=>t.FLAG==0).Count>0)).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Try this Linq, It may help you

```
var linqQuery= from pa in parent_list where pa.Flag==0
               select ch in pa.child_type_list where ch.Flag==0
               select new 
               { 
                 id=ch.id, 
                 Parent_Type_Id=ch.Parent_Type_Id.ID,
                 Name=ch.Parent_Type_Id.Name,    
                 ChildName=ch.Name,
                 Flag=ch.Flag
                };
```